# add a column to pandas dataframe based on row name, if row doesnt exist add it in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have the following data frames with df1 been my master

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '10'], ['b', '20']],
               columns=['letter', 'Jan'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '2']],
               columns=['letter', 'feb'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '10'], ['b', '20'], ['c', '20'], ['d', '20']],
               columns=['letter', 'march'])
```

how can I add df2 then df3 to df1 so it looks like the following.

```
 Letter jan feb march
0   a     10  1   10
1   b     20  2   20
2   c         2   20
3   d             20



res = pd.concat([df1, df2,df3])
```

I tired this and the letter keeps getting added in which is not what i want

```
  letter  Jan  feb march
0      a   10  NaN   NaN
1      b   20  NaN   NaN
0      a  NaN    1   NaN
1      b  NaN    2   NaN
2      c  NaN    2   NaN
0      a  NaN  NaN    10
1      b  NaN  NaN    20
2      c  NaN  NaN    20
3      d  NaN  NaN    20

```

Any idea how i can solve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution of your problem.

```
df_outer = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='letter', how='outer')
df_outer = pd.merge(df_outer, df3, on='letter', how='outer')
df_outer = df_outer.fillna('')
df_outer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) to **outer** merge the dataframes `df1`, `df2` and `df3` on `letter` then use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill the `NaN` values:

```
df = (
    df1.merge(df2, on='letter', how='outer')
    .merge(df3, on='letter', how='outer').fillna('')
)
```

OR, If having large number of dataframes which requires merging we can use more concise solution using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) + [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) and pass the list of dataframes which require merging to the `reduce` function:

```
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda x, y:
            pd.merge(x, y, on='letter', how='outer'), [df1, df2, df3]).fillna('')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

  letter Jan feb march
0      a  10   1    10
1      b  20   2    20
2      c       2    20
3      d            20
```